# Proper URI for mlflow models predict CLI

Tags: python, mlflow

I have a remote mlflow server up and running. I have also a model in its artifact store. mlflow provides a snippet that can be used for inference:

```
import mlflow
logged_model = 'runs:/d3d28efecca44e728a8520d9392267e4/model'
mlflow.set_tracking_uri("http://my.server.address:5001")
# Load model as a PyFuncModel.
loaded_model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(logged_model)
```

This works fine and the model is loaded, I can use it to predict new values.

Now I'd like to use `mlflow models predict` API and I tried many different combinations, but nothing works. I tried this:

```
set MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI=http://my.server.address:5001
mlflow models predict -m 'runs:/d3d28efecca44e728a8520d9392267e4/model' -i 'newdata.csv'

mlflow models predict -m 'http://my.server.address:5001/runs:/d3d28efecca44e728a8520d9392267e4/model' -i 'newdata.csv'

mlflow models predict -m 'http://my.server.address:5001/mlartifacts/d3d28efecca44e728a8520d9392267e4/artifacts/model' -i 'newdata.csv'

mlflow models predict -m 'mlflow-artifacts://my.server.address:5001/mlartifacts/2/d3d28efecca44e728a8520d9392267e4/artifacts/model' -i 'newdata.csv'
```

and many others but nothing works. I get "Bad URL" error. How should I provide the uri to my model? The documentation here https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html#id14 doesn't cover the topic deeply, I think.

An extra remark - the artifact store is proxied by the remote tracking server, my client has no access to it directly, as described here https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html#scenario-5-mlflow-tracking-server-enabled-with-proxied-artifact-storage-access

Comment: When passing the URI as an environment variable you need to set it with `export MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI=http://my.server.address:5001`.  I am unsure if that solves your problem but at least `mlflow` can see its value this way.

Comment: Your setup is not 100% clear to me but in general the combination of `export MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI=...` and `mlflow models predict -m 'runs:/.../model'` does work.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the case. On Windows one sets env vars with 'set' (the equivalent of 'export' in Linux). Snd as You can see the MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI has been set with the very first command

Comment: OK sorry about me thinking only in Linux.